# Tailwind arbitrary background-position values

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

The docs say that with the `jit` mode you can use arbitrary values for background positioning, giving the example:

`<div class="bg-[center_top_1rem]">`

But this isn't an arbitrary css value like say `80px`.

Is there any documentation for this syntax?

1rem obviously offsets the `top` value, but how would I also offset the `center`? My guess of `bg-[center_2rem_top_1rem]` doesn't work.

I'm also surprised that something like `bg-[0% 20%]` doesn't work, especially as I've seen it suggested as answers to other questions.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question. It is picking up the background position with a `3-value syntax` which is documented here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position

**Example 1**

`bg-[center_top_1rem]`

The `center` keyword value defines X. `top` keyword value defines Y, and `1rem` defines the offset value for Y.

**Example 2**

`[center_2rem_top_1rem]`

Your example does work, and will create the following css. It centres the image on the x-axis and then offsets by `2rem`.

```
.bg-\[center_2rem_top_1rem\] {
  background-position: center 2rem top 1rem;
}
```

**Example 3**

`[left_2rem_top_1rem]`

The effect is more obvious when we set the background-image to the left and then add an offset.

**Example 4**

`bg-[0% 20%]`

Any spaces should use an underscore so at least it should be `bg-[0%_20%]` but I couldn't get it to work with percentage values. It did work with keywords `bottom_right`

Here are all the examples, https://play.tailwindcss.com/uKNZ5jEcOK

You can see the CSS created in the Utilities tab of the Generated CSS tab.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I guess I just wasn't aware of underscore separated values, and hadn't thought about that in conjunction with the 3 value syntax. I managed to make the percentages work with the 4 value syntax described in your link `bg-[top_0%_left_100%]`